# Twitter Helper with webmatrix issue. Displays blank page

Tags: asp.net, twitter, webmatrix, helper

I'm attempting to teach myself ASP.Net and I've decided to start with web pages so I'm going through the tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/intro-to-web-pages-programming)

The problem I'm running into is that I can't get the Twitter helper to work. I just get a blank page and can't figure out what the issue is. I have checked to make sure the Twitter helper is installed and intellsense recognizes the TwitterGoodie methods. Here is my code...

```
@{

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>twittertest</title>
    </head>
        <body>
          <div> 
            @TwitterGoodies.Search("webmatrix")
          </div> 
        </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package referenced in the article you linked to uses version 1.0 of the Twitter API which was deprecated in June 2013. Hence nothing appears on your page. If you want a Twitter widget to appear on a page, go and get one directly from them: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new